# How should I wrap this shirt around this character's waist?

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

I'm working on clothing for a character model.

[image: The character, with the flannel in the base position.]

My goal is to wrap the flannel around the character's waist. I've created a shape key for the base position to UV unwrap and texture it, and another shape key for the wrapped position.

I've tried using both the cloth brush with grab deformation as well as the elastic deform brush to achieve this. My two biggest issues are that the sleeves of the flannel clip into themselves (which will probably be fixed after running a cloth sim with self collisions) and the cuffs come apart.

[image: Clipping of a sleeve.]

[image: The cuffs, after coming apart.]

I've created a vertex group for the cuffs to easily make a face set out of, in hopes that I could freely drag the cuffs around and the sleeves would follow. Kind of like how this arm follows this hand and the hand doesn't deform at all.

[image: An arm following a hand.]

Instead, I get this:

[image: Attempting to sculpt the flannel into the desired position.]

...and with face sets boundary auto-masking on:

[image: Attempting to sculpt the flannel into the desired position, with face sets boundary auto-masking on.]

What's the best way to accomplish this while keeping the cuffs intact? You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dvwOTw2qPT04oEWBseDa5Wh1DhNav7dh/view?usp=sharing)!

Thanks again!